# Move Question From Superuser

Tags: support, super-user

Can this question be moved from Superuser? Or is there a way I can use it?
https://superuser.com/questions/1491066/errors-2502-2503-when-installing-msis?noredirect=1#comment2249939_1491066

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag the question on Superuser and ask a moderator to move the question.

A SU moderator can move it, I can't from my side initiate the move.

I think SU got a chat room with all moderators inside it, so they can answer fast too; https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator

I suggest some edits to include the correct tag, windows server 2016, and the why of the question. As do you try to push the MSI throught a script or from GPO ? such background will help to answer you.